# Fortran 90 logical kind mismatch

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I'm trying to pass an argument declared simply as `logical :: invar`
to a function where the receiving variable is declared as

`logical(x) :: invar`

Now `x` is defined as

`INTEGER, PARAMETER :: x = KIND(.TRUE.)`

What does that definition of `x` mean? I did a search for `kind(.true.)` but all results kind of brush this aspect aside. Would appreciate some clarification for an expert.

I'm using the Intel compiler, if this has something to do with the compiler.

Comment: You write about some mismatch in the title. Do you get any error, or are you just concerned if everything is as it should be?

Comment: Good point @VladimirF - if there's mismatch please post the error and code. If you're just trying to understand, see my answer.

Comment: Apologies, yes, I do get a mismatch error if I do not declare invar as logical(x) :: invar.
The error simply says that the types do not match. So I'm trying to understand this syntax so that I can avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables such as real numbers, integers, and even logicals can be different `kind`s. Typically, this is important to distinguish between single precision and double precision reals, for example. In my experience, there's no reason to fiddle with the `kind` of a logical.

Whoever wrote this code, obviously, thinks otherwise. When you declare a logical in the usual way, with

```
logical :: L1
```

the variable `my_logical` is of the default kind. When you declare it using

```
integer, parameter :: x = KIND(.TRUE.)
integer(x) :: L2
```

it has the kind of `x`, which is defined to be the kind of `.true.`. The tricky part is that `.true.` is almost certainly *also* of the default kind. (The standard requires that the default kind is the kind of `.FALSE.`)

So, in the examples above, `L1` and `L2` are of the same kind. I don't know why somebody would bother with defining the default logical kind as `x`, but you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: `.true.` isn't just "almost certainly" of default kind, but "totally, entirely, cannot be more certain, absolutely is, someone should get fired if it isn't" of default kind.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :-) I get it now.